# mobile flex application Basic UI tutorials need

Tags: android, apache-flex

i want to develop a Flex based android application--

I don't know basic ui components and layouts 
please any one give me the links for beginner tutorials of mobile flex app development

I want detail tutorials to build ui components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need code examples for both mobile and desktop development, the best you can find for beginners is the **Tour de Flex**: http://flex.org/tour/

That and google :) IMHO, you should post questions here only if you have some real problem in your development, not tutorial requests.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the docs on [Developing Mobile Applications with Adobe Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/index.html)

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: it's that much efficient please give me some more links

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question.  Have you done any research yourself? If you want more links, then Google the topic; then tell us why those searches are not bringing back satisfactory results.